# Swift error: Cannot assign to property: 'coordinate' is immutable

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit

The problem is when I write this line of code on which I try to convert the user location to another coordinate, I get this error: Cannot assign to property: 'coordinate' is immutable

The code is:

```
var location = sender.location(in: self.mapView)
let locCoord = self.mapView.convert(location, toCoordinateFrom: self.mapView)
self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate = locCoord   *// Cannot assign to property:'coordinate' is immutable*
```

Can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says the `coordibate` property is immutable

```
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get }
var userLocation: CLLocation { get }
```

you can't alter it in addition to `userLocation`  , if you need a different location go directly with

Comment: How to do that? Sorry I didn't understand your answer. I just need the device location changing programmatically by taps

Comment: device location can't be faked

Comment: But it can be done by Debug>Locations>Custom Place. This means it can be done programmatically, too, I think. Am I wrong?

Comment: you can change what the mapview is currently showing by changing the region but userlocation will remain as it is according to where the user exists

Comment: @AnthonSanthez no, thats just for debugging. I'm pretty sure apple doesn't allow you to spoof device location from code?

Comment: but there are some applications like that which alter the current location. For the game pokemonGo for example

Comment: @AnthonSanthez I think they don't use the user location, but simply send custom locations to the game. This way they can easily alter the coordinates with a certain delta when moving around.

Comment: @Thijs van der Heijden You mean sending custom locations through xcode by a cable connected to the phone, but not by independent usage of the phone itself along with a spoofer app?

Comment: Apparently you can use GPX files to spoof location, its quite complicated as far as I know, but doable. You should look up some information about those files and how they work. I'm not sure Apple would allow an app that uses those files on the app store, as apps that I know spoof location always have to be downloaded via safari.

Comment: @Thijs van der Heijden I couldn't find such a restriction statement when I googled it for a week, that's why I tried to find a solution. If it's sure not legal for appstore, than no need to work around anymore:)

Comment: Don't take my word for it. I just don't know of any location spoofing apps on the app store. It could be that they do accept them! You should ask apple.

Answer (score 0):

If your want to assign new value then use var instead of let , let is used to non changed values

Comment: you mean var locCoord ? I want to change the value of userlocation.coordinate

Comment: change locCoord to var yes , self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate cannot be changed since it gets value from device's location so what you can do as i understand you case is to save the coordinate value in a var property and keep change the value depends on coordinate value received by the MapKit like so :


var locCoord = self.mapView.convert(location, toCoordinateFrom: self.mapView)
if locCoord !=  self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate {
locCoord = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate
}